# Use of default SSL cert/key on MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql

I've a Percona MySQL 5.7 ( 5.7.21-20-log) installed using `apt-get`, when I connect it using the root account and check the ssl status

```
# mysql --ssl
mysql> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| have_openssl  | YES             |
| have_ssl      | YES             |
| ssl_ca        | ca.pem          |
| ssl_capath    |                 |
| ssl_cert      | server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                 |
| ssl_crl       |                 |
| ssl_crlpath   |                 |
| ssl_key       | server-key.pem  |
+---------------+-----------------+

mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21-20, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  6.3

Connection id:      31
Current database:
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Cipher in use is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

So by default, SSL is being used.
However, when I use the full command

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root  -p  --ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem --ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem --ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem
```

It return error

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: If you type `status;` in a mysql prompt, does it say SSL is used?

On a side note, if you can, I'd use a VPN to encrypt your MySQL traffic. I've always found the SSL setup very cumbersome, and it creates a lot of extra overhead on a connection, which is especially annoying if every request on a webserver initiates a MySQL connection.

Comment: @Halfgaar Yes, SSL is using as edited

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is using server certificate and key on the client side.

```
--ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem --ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem
```

As documented in [6.4.2 Command Options for Encrypted Connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-options.html) (emphasis is mine):

> ```
> --ssl-cert=file_name
> ```
>
> The path name of the SSL public key certificate file in PEM format. **On
>   the client side, this is the client public key certificate**. On the
>   server side, this is the server public key certificate. On the server
>   side, this option implies `--ssl`.
>
> ```
> --ssl-key=file_name
> ```
>
> The path name of the SSL private key file in PEM format. On the client
>   side, this is the **client private key**. On the server side, this is the
>   server private key. On the server side, this option implies `--ssl`.

You can force the TLS connection using `--ssl`, alone:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p --ssl
```

Useful here might also be the `--ssl-cipher=cipher_list`. With it you can verify that the connection doesn't use any cipher you don't want even when allowed on the server configuration. However, when you have power over both, this should be configured primarily on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understood in 5.7 `--ssl` is enough, but if I want to specify using the old way, where I can find the default client cert/key instead of generate a custom one?

Comment: You could [create](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html#creating-ssl-files-using-openssl-unix-command-line) and sign them with the same `ca.pem`.